# How to close tabs on Microsoft Edge programmatically

Tags: c#, tabs, microsoft-edge

I am trying to close all of the opened tabs on Microsoft Edge from c# code but can't get it working.
tried:

```
Process[] edgeProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdgeCP");

foreach (Process theprocess in edgeProcessList)
{
    if (theprocess.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(theprocess.MainWindowHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{W}");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

as well as:

```
foreach(Process proc in edgeProcessList.ToList())
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

but neither work.  The processes do get killed But new ones re-appear at once.

Shows both in debug after:

```
Process[] newProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdgeCP");
```

as well as in the task manager.
Is there a way to do this that works?

Answer (score 3):

### the process is named "msedge"

```
Process[] Edge = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge");
            foreach (Process Item in Edge)
            {
                try
                {
                    Item.Kill();
                    Item.WaitForExit(30000);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

See [WebDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver)

That appears to be what "driver" in the incomplete answer is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Code to kill Edge browser instance

```
Process[] Edge = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge");
            foreach (Process Item in Edge)
            {
                try
                {
                    Item.Kill();
                    Item.WaitForExit(3000);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

using System.Windows.Automation and Keyboard Hook

```c
            Process[] procsEdge = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge");
            foreach (Process Edge in procsEdge)
            {
                if (Edge.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Edge.MainWindowHandle);
                    var tabs = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem));
                    var elmUrl = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
                    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in tabs)
                    {
                        if (elmUrl != null)
                        {
                            AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrl.GetSupportedPatterns();
                            if (patterns.Length > 0)
                            {
                                ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrl.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                                string url = val.Current.Value;
                                Console.WriteLine(url.Contains("bing.com"));
                            }
                        }
                        tabitem.SetFocus();
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ALT+W}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out and wrote some code that I got to work:

```
var tabs = driver.WindowHandles;

var x = Enumerable.Range(1, tabs.Count - 1).Reverse();

foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(1, tabs.Count-1).Reverse())
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[i]);
    driver.Close();
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: This answer is useless to readers as it does not define the type of `driver`. There is no context around this answer in relation to the original question. Please give a complete answer.

Comment: and the `Driver` should be?